# How to create a column in r dataframe conditional on other columns

Tags: r

I am trying a create a new column conditional on the present columns. 
Condition is a matching condition for which I am using grep function.

The data goes like this

```
            Keyword                         CPC     Impr   Clicks  
    singapore and malaysia tour packages    3.62    241    14     
    +singapore +holiday +packages           3.62    5      0              
    singapore tour packages from bangalore  3.62    201    12     
    "star cruise singapore"                 22.14   31     1    
    [singapore tourism]                     7.30    489    51
```

So, the first column Keyword has "", [],+ symbols. I want to match these symbols to create a new column
with characters like Phrase Match, Exact Match and Broad Match respectively.

I am using `grep` function for matching the symbols.
Please help me with a function to do the create a new column based on the matching condition.

Below are some of the codes that I have written (which ofcourse are throwing errors:(  ). Please review them and advise.

---

```
pattern<- "[/+]"
pattern1<- "(\\[.*?\\])"
singapore$type<-ifelse(grep('"',singapore$Keyword),as.character("Phrase Match"),
                       ifelse(grep(pattern,singapore$Keyword),as.character("Broad Match"),
                              ifelse(grep(pattern1, singapore$Keyword), as.character("Exact Match"))))
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, type, value = c("Phrase Match", "Phrase Match",  : 
  replacement has 71 rows, data has 113
```

---

```
func<-function(i)
for(i in 1:length(singapore$Keyword)){
    singapore$type<- i
    if(singapore[grep('"',singapore$Keyword),]){
        i==as.character("Phrase Match")
    }elseif(singapore[grep("[/+]",singapore$keyword),]){
        i==as.character("Broad Match")
    }else(singapore[grep("(\\[.*?\\])", singapore$Keyword),]){
        i==as.character("EXact Match")   
    }
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"        i==as.character("Phrase Match")
    }elseif"
>         i==as.character("Broad Match")
Error: object 'i' not found
>     }else(singapore[grep("(\\[.*?\\])", singapore$Keyword),]){
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
>         i==as.character("EXact Match")   
Error: object 'i' not found
>     }
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

---

Answer (score 0):

### First approach

For your first issue, use `grepl` instead of `grep` since this returns a logical i.e. TRUE/FALSE statement. In you last `ifelse` call you have no argument for what to return on false, so the function doesn't know what to return.
Also the `as.character()` statements are not necessary.

```r
singapore$type<-ifelse(grepl('"',singapore$Keyword),"Phrase Match",
                       ifelse(grepl(pattern,singapore$Keyword),"Broad Match",
                              ifelse(grepl(pattern1, singapore$Keyword), "Exact Match", NA)))
```

I'm also not sure if your expressions will achieve the desired outcome but this is a different question.

### Second approach

You don't need a `for` loop. In R it is usually better to familiarize oneself with the `apply` family. Your first version should be much better fixable.
There is a multitude of construction errors of the loop and the if-statements.
For example it isn't necessary to declare `func<-function(i)`

In the second line you're assigning the value of `i` to a new column called `type`, in every iteration of the loop.

In every conditional statement in the `if`/`ifelse` constructs you're passing the output of grep to select a data frame column.

In general if you want boolean evaluation you should use `grepl` and not `grep`.
I suggest you read for example this https://www.w3schools.in/r/conditional-statements/

Comment: Thank you!. The first part worked. 
And thanks for the advice on the second part